# C++ - Initializing class member with an instance

Tags: c++, class, initialization-list

my question is as follows: Suppose I have:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}
    void setInt(int i) { myInt = i; }
    int getInt() { return myInt; }
private:
    int myInt;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Foo f) { /* do something with f.getInt() */ }
};
```

Now I have another class that has Bar as a member vairable:

```
class BarUser
{
public:
    BarUser();
private:
    Bar bar;
};
```

I want to write BarUser's constructor, however I want to initialize Bar with a Foo member that has 3 as its integer. I.e.:

```
Foo f;
f.setInt(3);
Bar b(f);
```

However since I have Bar as a class member, I cannot write all this code in the initialization list... What I mean is:

```
BarUser::BarUser() : bar(/* Foo after executing f.setInt(3) */)
{ ... }
```

Suppose assignment operator is not allowed for Bar - how can I initialize it as intended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change `Foo`, write a function:

```
Foo make_foo(int i) { 
     Foo f; 
     f.setInt(i); 
     return f;
}
```

then initialize with `bar(make_foo(3))`.

You've sort of shot yourself in the foot by giving `Foo` a constructor but no `int` constructor. You might be better off adding an `explicit` constructor to `Foo` that takes an `int`.